# Integrating webhook receiver into GitLab pipelines

Tags: continuous-integration, twilio, gitlab-ci, webhooks

I would like to add integration tests to my SMS notification code delivering text messages using Twilio.

Currently, I am running some tests as a part of my pipeline as:

```
golang_test:
  extends: .golang_test
  stage: validate
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never
    - when: always
  tags:
    - private
    - test
    - us
  services:
    - name: postgres:9.6@sha256:e...4b8
      alias: notifications-db
  variables:
    DATABASE_HOST: notifications-db
    DATABASE_NAME: notifications
    POSTGRES_DB: notifications
    POSTGRES_USER: app_user
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
```

I already have a test texting an outbound SMS message. Starting a `webhook` listener to parse Twilio events is not a big deal.

However, a webhook has to be on some routable endpoint. How could I easily connect my listener running under docker with the receiver endpoint?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You want to run a webserver in your pipeline? Maybe use `services:` for that or just start your webhook listener using `docker run` ? If you have tried these approaches without success, what problem did you run into specifically? If those solutions are not sufficient or if I've misunderstood the goal, could you please clarify?

Comment: The problem is for such a web server's listening socket to be a publically routable endpoint accessible on the internet. Anyone can run a server and a client on a local subnet. It's being done all the time for various purposes. How would you @sytech go about making your `docker run` or whatever accessible to servers not running on the local "gitlab" subnet?

Comment: Although it's ill-advised to do this, it is _possible_ with self-hosted runners. If you bind the host docker socket to the runner (add `/var/run/docker.sock` to volumes and enable privileged job containers) then `docker run` in a job works just like using `docker run` on the host. If the host ports are internet-exposed, port bindings in your job are exposed on the host and thus are internet-accessible.